# Pnotify and fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, pnotify

I am using pnotify and loading callback function to show a notification when the fullcalendar plugin has loaded all events.

```
loading:function(isLoading, view){

    if (isLoading === false){
        new PNotify({
            title:"Finished loading events",
            type:'success',
            delay: 1000
        });
```

My problems is that when ever I move to different dates it calls loading again so I am left with so many notifications shown on my screen that it becomes very unusable. How can I bypass this? Is there a way to check if a notification is active and just change the text and title of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add that logic based on the template you're using ([check the template docs](http://sciactive.com/pnotify/#theming)).

Your code would be something like

```
loading:function(isLoading, view){
    var exists = false;
    $(".ui-pnotify-title").each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == 'Finished loading events')
            exists = true;
    });

    if (!exists) {
        new PNotify({
            title:"Finished loading events",
            type:'success',
            delay: 1000
        });
    }
}
```

It would be better if you could use a specific id or class to detect if the notification is already shown, but this works.

Take a look at [**the working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ne7mo4uq/).

Comment: hmmmm, yes, but that won't change the logic? If I change views and reloading events happens, if I am showing a notification already it might the notification will be showing Finished loading events while fullcalendar is loading new ones. It should to just alter the text or remove the old one and show a new one (even better). What I really wanted was to show two notifications one for starting loading (isLoading == true) and one for finish (isLoading==false) but the issue with too many notifs showing up was a draw back. Maybe it's too tiring to always show this. Maybe is better to add a spinner

Comment: I would stick with a spinner because it's also less intrusive to the user (user experience point of view). If you want to show two notifications, you just have to adapt the code I provided to suit your needs.

Comment: That's what I thought also, I think I am going for the spinner option.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store it in a variable, do your necessary code (like nullable/undefined checks, etc) and call "update()" (here:  http://sciactive.com/pnotify/ - for example, find for 'Click Notice' and see the source)

```
var p = new PNotify({
    title: 'Some title',
    text: 'Check me out! I\'m a error.',
    type: 'error',
    icon: 'fa fa-times-circle'          
});
// ... code ...
p.update({title: 'My new title'});
```